# 'class omnetpp::cOsgCanvas' has no member 'getScene()'

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins, inet

I am trying to install and build the inet framework (veins + simulte integration) in Omnet++. When I build it, I get 'class omnetpp::cOsgCanvas' has no member 'getScene()'. The error is on line 60 of /inet/src/common/geometry/common/CoordinateSystem.cc Does anyone know how to remedy this issue? I would really like to check out the example simulations for reference. Thanks!

Comment: Which versions of OMNeT++ and INET do you use?

Comment: @JulianHeinovski Omnet++ 5.1.1 and INET 3.6.0

Comment: @JulianHeinovski The guide that I was following can be found at http://simulte.com/add_veins.html